# Wrapper.html() is empty in jest + Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuex

I am trying to test my vue app using jest,  but all wrapper's properties and menthods  are undefined.

```
import Dashboard from "../../src/views/mail/Dashboard.vue";
import Vue from "vue";
import { mount, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";

jest.mock("../../src/views/mail/Dashboard.vue", () => ({
  name: "Dashboard",
  render: jest.fn(),

  getters: () => ({
    "auth-token": {
      token:
        "ey...",
      exp: "2023-02-23",
    },
  }),
}));

describe("dashboard.js", () => {
  let getters;
  let store;

  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue.use(Vuex);
 });

  test("Wrapper exists", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Dashboard, { store, localVue });
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true); // this passes  
 });
  test("wrapper attributes should be identified", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Dashboard, { store, localVue });
    console.log("HTML =", wrapper.html()); // this is empty
  });
```

I was expecting to get some html elements in wrapper but its empty. wrapper.find(/*some id*/)  returns ErrorWrapper which I believe means wrapper cannot find that id.

Comment: You are mocking your component with an empty render function, so indeed the html is empty.

Comment: Then if i remove the render function then Im getting this error 
`
console.error
    [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
    
    found in
    
    ---> <Dashboard>
           <Root>
`

Comment: You need a render function or template for sure, but what are you expecting in your `wrapper.html()` if you mock it with an empty result? If you mock it like `template: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("<div>Test</div>")` then your component template will contain this.

Comment: No I dont want to do that.  I want to access the <Dashboard> component. I saw many questions on stack overflow which gives different answers, but none of those work. 

Like adding .default to require. and calling Dashboard as Vue.component ('dashboard')

Comment: So why are you even mocking your Dashboard component if you want to use the real one? Just remove your `jest.mock` line and mock what you need to mock in your component in the `mount` function.

Comment: Yes. I removed the mock function and now I am getting `
  console.error
    [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
    
    found in
    
    ---> <Anonymous>
           <Root>
`